# Слишком большой размер файла image.jpg и style.css

Tags: css, frontend, webpack

Помогите пожалуйста уже неделю как не могу правильно собрать файлы показывает warning

```
WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (250 kB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets:
  office.jpg (268 kB)

WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (250 kB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
  main (456 kB)
      bundle.js
      style.css


WARNING in webpack performance recommendations:
You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
```

Покажу ошибку на примере моего **webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
const webpack = require("webpack");
const tinypngCompress = require("webpack-tinypng-compress");

const config = {
    entry: "./common.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename:"bundle.js",
        publicPath:"dist/"
    },
    // performance: {
    //  maxEntrypointSize:400000
    // },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                use:"babel-loader",
                test: /\.js$/,
            },
            {
                loader:ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    loader:"css-loader",
                    options: {minimize:true}
                }),
                test: /\.css$/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader:"url-loader"
                        // options:{ limit:1000, name:"[name].[ext]" } 
                    },
                    "image-webpack-loader"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }, 
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("style.css"),
    ]
};
if (NODE_ENV == "production") {
    config.plugins.push(
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress:{
                warnings:false,
                drop_console:true,
                unsafe:true
            }
        })
    );
}
module.exports = config;
```

Как видите там есть закоментированный options(внизу loader-а) в таком порядке webpack выдает ошибку

```
WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (250 kB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets:
  style.css (448 kB)

WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (250 kB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
  main (456 kB)
      bundle.js
      style.css


WARNING in webpack performance recommendations:
You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
```

Если раскомментировать строку `options` то получу ошибку что картинка слишком много весит вот оригинал ошибки

```
WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (250 kB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets:
  office.jpg (291 kB)

WARNING in webpack performance recommendations:
You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
```

Comment: Проблема связана с тем что `loader:"url-loader"` преобразовывет картинки в DataURI и пихает их в CSS и JS файлы. Попробуйте заменить модуль `loader:"url-loader"` на `loader: 'file-loader'`(https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader) должно помочь.

Comment: @ДмитрийМирошниченко нет не помогло к сожалению :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил мою проблему данный код

```
npm i webpack webpack-cli --save-dev
```

Скачивание и установка webpack 4 Legato